# useDisclosure() not a function chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: (0 , *chakra_ui_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.useDisclosure) is not a function

im importing useDisclosure correctly from chakraUI but it says  [useDisclosure() not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW4LQ.png)

here is my code
[code for a sidebar/drawer component using ChakraUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Lpa.png)

Comment: Can you provide the github repo?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NextJS make sure to use client component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hay!

Try this code and tell me if you get the same error.

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  Drawer,
  DrawerBody,
  DrawerFooter,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerOverlay,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerCloseButton,
  useDisclosure,
  Button,
  Input,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'


const DrawerExample = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
  const btnRef = React.useRef()

  return (
    <>
      <Button ref={btnRef} colorScheme='teal' onClick={onOpen}>
        Open
      </Button>
      <Drawer
        isOpen={isOpen}
        placement='right'
        onClose={onClose}
        finalFocusRef={btnRef}
      >
        <DrawerOverlay />
        <DrawerContent>
          <DrawerCloseButton />
          <DrawerHeader>Create your account</DrawerHeader>

          <DrawerBody>
            <Input placeholder='Type here...' />
          </DrawerBody>

          <DrawerFooter>
            <Button variant='outline' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button colorScheme='blue'>Save</Button>
          </DrawerFooter>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  )
}

export default DrawerExample;
```

If everything is ok, then try copying the imports and running your code

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your code, still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of Chakra UI are you using?